# Did Air Europe fly to Toronto from Lamezia Terme?

Tags: aviation-history, airlines, flight-path

I am looking for more information regarding a flight from Lamezia Terme (SUF) to Toronto Pearson (YYZ) that according to some of the people I spoke to used to be operated by Air Europe around 1993.

I have researched [wikipedia's Air Europe page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Europe) and it looks like they have never even had an aircraft capable of servicing the [4,087 nm route](http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=suf-yyz&DU=nm&DM=&SG=&SU=mph).

Has any of you any idea of how I could retrieve more detailed information? For example, is there any way of knowing which airlines operated the route back in 1993?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia page [you checked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Europe) is for the British Air Europe. The Italian airline of [the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Europe_(Italy)) operated [12 Boeing 767](https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/search?fleet=Air-Europe-(Italy)&manufacturer=Boeing&subtype=767-300&fleetStatus=historic&sort=dd)'s in the 90's.

The image below shows the Italian airline at Toronto in the mid-90's.

[image]
([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Air-Europe/Boeing-767-35H-ER/228043))

The 767-300ER shown above is capable of reaching the West Coast of the US from Italy.

[image]
(gcmap.com) The [Boeing 767-300ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_767#Specifications) has a range of 5,980 NM.

Comment: This is very interesting and exciting! Thanks! So I take that route could have been operated with a Boeing 767-300.

Comment: @FaCoffee It was actually a 767-300ER, so yes. [The -300 only has 3,900 nmi range, but the -300ER has 5980 nmi range.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_767#Specifications)

Answer (score 0):

This airline flew out of Toronto between 1990-1996 in the summertime only. It sold tickets through AlbaTours and it flew nonstop to Lamezia, Pescara, Rome CIA, Milan and Venice. It started off with the 757 making stops in Dublin/Shannon and then in 1992 it switched over to the 767 which made the journey nonstop.

Comment: Welcome to [Travel.SE]!  This is useful information, but it would be even better with citations.  If there are useful links you can provide, please edit your answer to include them.